# GetControlPivot() returns None during compute_gradients

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, tensorflow

During a call to compute_gradients I get the following error

```
File "...../tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2430, in AddOp
  self._AddOpInternal(op)
File "...../tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2467, in _AddOpInternal
  for x in external_inputs if x.outputs]
File "...../tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2467, in <listcomp>
  for x in external_inputs if x.outputs]
File "...../tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 79, in identity
  return gen_array_ops.identity(input, name=name)
File "...../tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 3263, in identity
  "Identity", input=input, name=name)
File "...../tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
  op_def=op_def)
File "...../tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3414, in create_op
  op_def=op_def)
File "...../tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1782, in __init__
  self._control_flow_post_processing()
File "...../tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1793, in _control_flow_post_processing
  self._control_flow_context.AddOp(self)
File "...../tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2430, in AddOp
  self._AddOpInternal(op)
File "...../tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2458, in _AddOpInternal
  self._MaybeAddControlDependency(op)
File "...../tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2496, in _MaybeAddControlDependency
  op._add_control_input(self.GetControlPivot().op)
```

There's more to the stacktrace in the higher levels but this appears more relevant. On the Ipython debugger I get the following additional information

```
ipdb> self
<tensorflow.python.ops.control_flow_ops.WhileContext object at 0x7fa4d32bf7b8>
ipdb> self.name
'gradients/RelnetBabi/map/while/RelnetBabi/StoryEmbedding/rnn/while/while_context'
ipdb> op
<tf.Operation 'gradients/b_count_13/Identity' type=Identity>
```

The 'rnn' in self.name above is an instance of tf.nn.dynamic_rnn. It appears that the while loop context created by the dynamic rnn does not have a "pivot". Any ideas on what could be the issue here?

i'm using Python 3.5 and tensorflow 1.9.0

Comment: Could you put together a snippet to reproduce? Does look like something weird going on with while_loop gradients. Is the while_loop in a restored MetaGraph (random guess)?